# AWS cloudformation resource already exists : deploy without deleting old resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I created and deployed a S3 resource (bucket) using cloudformation.
After that i deployed a version without that resource.
Then i deployed a version with the resource.

Since the bucket exists, it gives me an error that it cannot deploy.
This has happened to me before, in past times I deleted the resource and deployed again.
I'm looking for a way to use the resource for future deployments. It is the exact same resource, this is the yaml :

```
 Bucket:
   Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
   Properties:
     BucketName: !Sub "myBucketName"
```

Is there anything I can add to the resource, a policy, a unique ID, anything so that i could use the existing resource?

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up deleting the resource and deploying again. I am using SAM and it doesnt make sense to me that i try to deploy the same resource and i can't because it already exists. Importing it would be fine if i could do it automatically. Adding a unique ID also makes sense, as in, if its the same ID upsert the resource. Anyways, thanks for your help ! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "use the existing resource" in a CFN, you have to [import it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html). Also its a bad practice to keep modify resources created by CFN outside of CFN. This leads to [drift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html) and number of issues, one of which you are experiencing.